# Maven: creating 2 war files each with different web.xml?

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I need to create two WAR files with two different `web.xml` files using Maven. The WAR files are the same otherwise.

The WAR files are created as expected, however, the second file has the same `web.xml` file as the first.

How can I force the Maven WAR plugin to use the second file for the second WAR? I cannot use profiles since I need both files created in one pass.

My current code:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WEB</warSourceDirectory>
    <warName>main</warName>
    <webXml>${basedir}/CONF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>hist-war</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>war</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <warName>hist</warName>
        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WEB</warSourceDirectory>
        <webXml>${basedir}/CONF/hist.web.xml</webXml>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have just found another option and it seems to work in my case (from this [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#filtering)): `filteringDeploymentDescriptors` configuration property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) feature of the [Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

You need two WAR projects. The first is your original one, with its `web.xml` file in the correct place. This doesn't have any specific needs in terms of configuration. Just ensure that it builds as you expect.

The second only contains its POM and the alternate `web.xml` in the `WEB-INF` directory. This project's POM must contain a dependency on the first project with type specified as war and scope specified as runtime. You should not need to explicitly configure the Maven WAR plugin.

Comment: It may not work since web.xml can't be overlayed (based on this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mavens-war-overlay-what-are))and this quote: "One more gotcha that might arise out of this would be dealing with the web.xml. The overlay's web.xml file is NOT copied over nor is it merged in any way, so if your overlay has specific web.xml file information you can either manually add it to the web.xml or use a <include file="/WEB-INF/web-overlay.xml"> tag where you've added the contents to a file named web-overlay.xml to the overlay war project."

Comment: What I'm proposing is to overlay the full, original WAR over a new one that only has the alternate `web.xml` file. This should work for exactly the reason mentioned in your comment.

Comment: How can I configure overlay so that it includes my hist.web.xml file in the right place with the right name? I am assuming that I would have to do use `<includes>` and include everything. But I am not sure about web.xml part. I was trying to do exactly that when I found a way I described me other post. However, I am still interested in finding how it would work with overlays. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems there are a variety of gotchas using the war plugin.  in this case, i would just use 2 separate sub-modules to build the appropriate wars.

Comment: This won't work as there must be a default value for webXml in configuration section outside executions (execution fails otherwise). If that section is included, there will be 3 wars produced, all the same with 3 different names (one of them will just have a default artifactId name). That's because there is always a default-war goal that is being executed.